# How do multiple query with mod_rewrite in Nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, mod-rewrite

I'm clearing the links with Mod_rewrite but It only works smoothly with a slug.

Unfortunately it does not work when there are multiple slugs.

For only 1 slug, for example [working]:

```
location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 last; 
        }
    }
```

For only 2 slug [not working]:

```
location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 break; 
            rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1&idno=$2 last; 
        }
```

How can I do more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the more specific regular expression first. Your regular expression `^/(.+)$` will match both the one-slug and the two-slug cases, so the second statement is never tested.

Also, you should use `rewrite...last` for both rewrite statements, as you are rewriting to a PHP script which will be processed in another `location` block.

For example:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1&idno=$2 last; 
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 last; 
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: I understand why now. Thank you for your time.